# How to parse String using Uri.parse

Tags: java, android, uri

I have a problem in getting a string and parsing it using `Uri.parse()` method.

I tried the following code:

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter);
String telephone = edit.getText().toString();
Uri number = Uri.parse(telephone);
```

but the application force closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to add the "`tel:`" prefix to your mobile number.

Comment: @DeX3 sorry for the misunderstanding. Thank you

Comment: @gmendes: If the above answer was the one you was looking for, make sure you do not forget to Mark it as the correct answer, so your question appears as resolved.